# react native import RNAndroidInstalledApps from 'react-native-android-installed-apps'; not working

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

i have been trying to get the list of apps installed on my mobile with the code below . but its show the error

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNInstalledApplication.getApps')

(npm dep:)

```
import RNAndroidInstalledApps from 'react-native-android-installed-apps';
     

const getApplication = ()=>{
   var s = RNAndroidInstalledApps.getApps()
  console.log(s)  }
```

is there any way to get list of installed apps on a mobile using react native packages